# Is there any way to programatically force "Always open files of this type" for a specific file type in Chrome?

Tags: .net, google-chrome

Basically my customer wants (much against my advice) to force all their users to have "Always open files of this type" for .docx files enabled in Chrome after their product has been installed on their computer. This so that "they won't be bothered with clicking *Open* after clicking a .docx link". Is there any way I can achieve this programatically from a .NET or C++ application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ANSWER: Yes

---

### STEPS

1. Go to the user's **Chrome user directory** (if windows, in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\<PROFILE>` where `<PROFILE>` is the current Chrome profile or the Chrome profile that the user wants this to be in effect for.  If only one profile exists for Chrome under this login, then the path would be `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. Edit the `preferences` file (that's right, no extension)... it's a ***JSON*** file, so any text editor will due.
3. Find the **`"extensions_to_open"`** entry under the **`"download"`** section:

> ```
>    "download": {
>       "default_directory": "E:\Installs\Wintel",
>       "directory_upgrade": true,
>       "extensions_to_open": "jpg:png:gif:pdf:xps",
>       "prompt_for_download": true
>    },
> ```
>
> Add, modify, or delete whatever file extensions you'd like.
>
> ---

### EXPLANATION

- Anything listed in the **`"extensions_to_open"`** field will no longer be prompted for a filename/location to save to, even for links to "files that normally get saved" - i.e. those that **do not** natively open -  (e.g. EXE, DOC, ZIP).
- Instead, those file types/extensions listed will now automatically open in their Operating System **associated** programs (e.g. MS Word for DOC files) as soon as the browser is done downloading the file.
- File types that **do** natively open in a browser (e.g. HTML, TXT, JS, CSS) will be unaffected by this and continue to open **IN THE BROWSER** and **NOT** in an **associated** program.

**NOTE:**  If IMAGE file types are listed in this **`"extensions_to_open"`** field, then those images will open in their Operating System **associated** programs **EVEN** if you *RIGHT-CLICK > SAVE AS...* on those images.  In any case (entry or not), *LEFT-CLICKing* on an image maintains the normal behavior, if one is set (e.g. through JavaScript, nested within an `<A HREF>`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

NO. Verified by testing.
Unfortunately, as of the current version, today, 9/10/2015, this option is NOT functional any longer. 
Seems that now they dictate which types will auto-open and that's it.