# Group policy to make Chrome open files automatically after download

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, download, registry, gpo

I am in the process of updating our currently existing Chrome distribution so that when a user downloads a .pdf file, the file is opened automatically.

As a first step, I was able to prevent Chrome from opening the pdf in its internal pdf viewer and could do a registry entry by using `AlwaysOpenPdfExternally`. This way it was downloading the file immediately and not opening it in the Chrome viewer.

I'd like to use Adobe to view the file automatically after download.
Unfortunately I was not able to find a registry entry. Nor was I able to find a GPO entry to be changed for Chrome.

I had found the following PowerShell script to be started upon logon of the user. However, testing it did not give me the result I was looking for.
The given entry `extensions_to_open` was not existing even after starting the script.

The current version of Chrome used is 66.255.

I would be happy for any help.

**Edit**: I am able to get the file to be opened automatically by inserting the given line here:
[Is there any way to programatically force "Always open files of this type" for a specific file type in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144948/is-there-any-way-to-programatically-force-always-open-files-of-this-type-for-a)
however, I am unsure of how to distribute the line of code into every PC in my network.

**Edit**: Chrome offers Group Policy Templates which should be importet into the active directory of your Windows Server. Once imported into your GPO, Chrome offers the setting: "Always open Pdf files externally". Once you check this feature, file should not automatically open in the internal PDF viewer.

Comment: This question is off topic for [so] - as you have no code it's not directly related to a coding issue. You're really asking how to distribute a script via GPO, this question is on-topics for [sf] - so I'm voting to move question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See second edit: import the latest group policy templates into the GPO (will be stored on the active directory). After that, go into the GPO policies for "Google Chrome" and check the feature "Always open PDF files externally".